# how to select a particular value from drop down

Tags: jquery, jsp, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

i am trying to select a value from a drop down menu.
my code currently looks like this:

```
var pnam= $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).html().trim();
    $("#parentModule_name").find("option").each(function(){
          if ($(this).text()==pnam) {
              $(this).attr('selected','selected');
          }
    });
```

the flow goes in the inner loop where the attribute is being selected correctly. however the expected result is not being achieved. 
funnily, on my page when i inspect the element this is what i get

```
<select id="parentModule_name" name="parentId">
                        <option value="0">Please Select</option>                                    
                                    <option value="12">Admin</option>




                                    <option value="13">Util</option>




                                    <option value="15" selected="selected">Vendor</option>




                                    <option value="16">Shubham</option>



                        </select>
```

so as u can see. the value is being selected correctly but not being displayed on the page. 
any help would be appreciated.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach is to filter the options and simply set the selected property;

```
$('#parentModule_name > option')
    .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == pnam; })
    .prop('selected', true);
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7RGgA/1/)

Answer (score 3):

The markup (or at least the selection portion of it) and script appear to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/7RGgA/

If you are executing this on page load, have you wrapped your script with `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var pnam= $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(1).html().trim();
    $("#parentModule_name").find("option").each(function(){
          if ($(this).text()==pnam) {
              $(this).attr('selected','selected');
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: @kevin.. the function i have mentioned in the snippet is a part of the full code.. i m invoking the function on the click of a button.. so there is no trouble there..
as i mentioned earlier.. 
everything seems to be working fine except for the selection of the option part.. is there something i can change there..

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("#parentModule_name").change(function () {
              var temp=  $(this).find("option:selected").text();
              alert(temp);
               });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
      $('#parentModule_name')
      .find('option[text="'+ pnam +'"]')
      .attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Comment: I think you might need to use `:contains(arg)`, rather than `[text=arg]`